# When, are making a promise

Tags: phrase-meaning, word-meaning

> **Ken Rhee**: The nationality part is very important, I think, because as a military officer, you're fighting for your country.
> When I entered the military in 2007 March
>
> **Sumi Yu**: In Korea?
>
> **Ken Rhee**: Yeah, I entered in March and got commissioned in July and ***when*** we get commissioned, we swear in..... basically, you ***are making a promise*** to your country.
> That's the first time that I felt that I had a country.
> Before that, I had to deal with so much racism in the US.
> When people tell you that you are not American and they tell you to go to China and they make fun of your eyes. It's like "Man, am I really American".
>
> **Sumi Yu**: How did you learn Korean?

[Source](https://youtu.be/pyHjui_YY48?t=6m10s)
(Time: from 6:10 to 7:00)

---

I'm not sure if "***when***" means "as soon as".

I'm not sure if "***are making a promise***" means "are in the middle of making a promise".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is transcribed speech and has some of the hesitation and mixed phrasing that is typical of speech.

The use of "when" is "at the time that".  It introduces a subordinate clause that indicates the time of the main clause.  But in this case the main clause gets mixed up. The main clause is "we swear in...."  but the speaker doesn't finish that sentence, but restarts "... basically...."

The general sense is "at the time that you get commissioned, and by the swearing-in process of getting commissioned, you are, in effect, making a promise to your country".

Comment: May I ask a question about your reply? I wonder if "some of the hesitation and mixed phrasing that is typical of speech" means "some of the hesitation, and some of the mixed  phrasing that is typical of speech".

Comment: yes, ... I suppose it can't have "all" the mixed phrasing...